# How can i run my own java process using zygote?

Tags: java, android

I want to run my own `java` process in android device, I am able to run it with dalvikvm (in `.dex` format). Because it is normal java process, it is not able to use some android library(`android.security.keystore`) `APIs`, even after adding required dependencies(`.jar`). Now I am thinking to launch my process using Zygote, because zygote is an incomplete version of an Android process–its memory space contains all the core libraries that are needed by any app. So, I wanna try whether it gives access to required libraries for my process. Is it possible to do so? And if yes, can you please provide me some info about how can I launch my own process using zygote.

Answer (score 0):

In short, no, you can't do this if your app is going to be an installable 3rd party app. Zygote is meant for launching Android apps which use the framework.

If you are building a custom platform and bundling this Java process as part of the platform you could possible launch it manually. But, it's out of the norm and you'd have to setup your own classpath and load different framework libs manually. Additionally, the framework libs are generally constructed to be used in the context of an Android framework based process, so you will likely have many problems getting this to work.